# Has anyone tried the new opengraph beta api with rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, facebook-opengraph

I'm wondering if anyone's given the new api introduced with rails yet?  I began a mock app through facebook and heroku and it actually generates the beginnings of a sinatra based project.  Has anyone crossed over to rails by chance?

Answer (score 3):

I'm actually working on an app using the new OpenGraph & Rails. With the [koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala), it's pretty easy for example to post an action on the timeline of an user, you just need to do a

```
res = api.put_connections(current_user.fbid, "namespace:verb", myobject: "link_to_my_object" )
```

And you will get the action's id in response if all it's fine.

Comment: Nice, this was 100% was I looking for!

Comment: Flavien, do you have a github with a test app?

Comment: Oh nope, sorry Simpleton... If I have some time, maybe I can create a simple one.

Answer (score 0):

I did the mock app too, and it works fine for the app (stuffed cookies).  I need to understand the javascript a bit more to move it over.